# How to convert this HTML code To php

Tags: php, html

I'm new to php and I have an HTML code which I want to write it in PHP. I've read that using

`echo "HTMLCODE";`

I can convert HTML codes to PHP but this aint worked out for me ..
My Sample Code in HTML:

```
   <fieldset style="float: left; position: absolute; left: 40%; top:  40%; background-color:pink;">
      <legend>Log in</legend>
        <table border="0" >
                    <td>Username </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="Username" id="Username" value=""></td>
                    <tr>      
                    </tr>
                    <td>Password </td>
                    <td><input type="password" name="Password" id="Password" value=""></td>
                    <tr>              
                    </tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" id="Submit" value="Enter"></td>
        </fieldset>
```

but when I write my code in php using the above rule I got syntax error !!! I just put a single line of my HTML code in php which gives error in netbeans 8.0

My code in PHP:

```
<php
        echo " <fieldset style="float: left; position: absolute; left: 40%; top:  40%; background-color:pink;">     
        </fieldset>";

?>
```

what am I missing here ? is it because of the style and semicolon which I use in style argument ? or I should use hyphon ' instead of quotation marks ?!!!

Comment: Quotes. Quotes. Quotes.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `"` is used as a string delimiter in PHP, you need to escape all the `"` characters in your HTML by pre-fixing them with a `\` sign.

```
echo "<fieldset style=\"float: left; position: absolute; left: 40%; top:  40%; background-color:pink;\">.....</fieldset>";
```

Or, alternatively, use `'` as a string delimiter, then the HTML can contain `"` characters, like so:

```
echo '<fieldset style="float: left; position: absolute; left: 40%; top:  40%; background-color:pink;">.....</fieldset>';
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace `"` by `\"`

So:

```
<php
        echo " <fieldset style=\"float: left; position: absolute; left: 40%; top:  40%;     background-color:pink;\">     
        </fieldset>";

?>
```

This also works:

```
<?php
echo '<fieldset style="float: left; position: absolute; left: 40%; top:  40%; background-color:pink;">';
echo '      <legend>Log in</legend>';
echo '        <table border="0" >';
echo '                    <td>Username </td>';
echo '                    <td><input type="text" name="Username" id="Username" value=""></td>';
echo '                    <tr>      ';
echo '                    </tr>';
echo '                    <td>Password </td>';
echo '                    <td><input type="password" name="Password" id="Password" value=""></td>';
echo '                    <tr>              ';
echo '                    </tr>';
echo '                    <td></td>';
echo '                    <td><input type="submit" id="Submit" value="Enter"></td>';
echo '        </fieldset>';
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the backslashes in the strings (used for the escape characters)

So-

```
echo " <fieldset style=\"float: left; position: absolute; left: 40%; top:  40%; background-color:pink;\">     
    </fieldset>";
```